# Format JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
[{"val":5,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},
{"val":2,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},
{"val":8,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},
{"val":1,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},
{"val":2,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-15"},
{"val":1,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-16"},
{"val":1,"sCategory":"12;#Cant get Access","CreatedDate":"2018-6-5"},
{"val":1,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-23"},
{"val":2,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-18"}]
```

I would like to have the following format in order to display dynamically:

```
[{"1;#Translation Incomplete": 5,"CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},
{"2;#VED incorrect/Missing": 2,"CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},
{"1;#Translation Incomplete": 8,"CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},
{"2;#VED incorrect/Missing": 1,"CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},
{"2;#VED incorrect/Missing": 2,"CreatedDate":"2018-5-15"},
{"1;#Translation Incomplete": 1,"CreatedDate":"2018-5-16"},
{"12;#Cant get Access": 1,"CreatedDate":"2018-6-5"},
{"1;#Translation Incomplete": 1,"CreatedDate":"2018-5-23"},
{"1;#Translation Incomplete": 2,"CreatedDate":"2018-5-18"}]
```

Basically I would like to group dynamically based on the `sCategory` field.
How can I achieve this with JavaScript?

Comment: What is the hard part of the task, i.e. where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop over the existing array and return the modified resulting array..
In each iteration, we grab the `sCategory` value and make it as a `key` and assign a value i=to it which existed to the `val` key. With `CreatedDate` we don't have to do anything.. just assign what already existed..

```js
let originalArr = [{"val":5,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},{"val":8,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-15"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-16"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"12;#Cant get Access","CreatedDate":"2018-6-5"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-23"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-18"}];

let newArr = originalArr.map((eachElem) => {
  return {[eachElem.sCategory]: eachElem.val, "CreatedDate": eachElem.CreatedDate}
})

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map for this:

```js
let input = [{"val":5,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},{"val":8,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-15"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-16"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"12;#Cant get Access","CreatedDate":"2018-6-5"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-23"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-18"}];

console.log(input.map(d => { r={}; r[d.sCategory] = d.val; r["CreatedDate"] = d.CreatedDate; return r}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Won't it be easier to just use the array as written so you are sure that each record has the properties val, cCategory and CreatedDate and just update the loop that creates the display?

Dynamic object properties are annoying to work with once you have to do things like sort by value or sort by sCategory.

```js
const input = [{"val":5,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},{"val":8,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-15"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-16"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"12;#Cant get Access","CreatedDate":"2018-6-5"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-23"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-18"}];
const output = input.map( entry => ( { [ entry.sCategory ] : entry.val, "CreatedDate": entry.CreatedDate } ) );
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to work with your object in JavaScript. Iterate through the array and create new object with the format that you want, then add it to a new array. You can also use the `map()` function, but the simple code below will run in all browsers:

```js
var json = [{
  "val": 5,
  "sCategory": "1;#Translation Incomplete",
  "CreatedDate": "2018-5-9"
}, {
  "val": 2,
  "sCategory": "2;#VED incorrect/Missing",
  "CreatedDate": "2018-5-11"
}, {
  "val": 8,
  "sCategory": "1;#Translation Incomplete",
  "CreatedDate": "2018-5-11"
}, {
  "val": 1,
  "sCategory": "2;#VED incorrect/Missing",
  "CreatedDate": "2018-5-9"
}, {
  "val": 2,
  "sCategory": "2;#VED incorrect/Missing",
  "CreatedDate": "2018-5-15"
}, {
  "val": 1,
  "sCategory": "1;#Translation Incomplete",
  "CreatedDate": "2018-5-16"
}, {
  "val": 1,
  "sCategory": "12;#Cant get Access",
  "CreatedDate": "2018-6-5"
}, {
  "val": 1,
  "sCategory": "1;#Translation Incomplete",
  "CreatedDate": "2018-5-23"
}, {
  "val": 2,
  "sCategory": "1;#Translation Incomplete",
  "CreatedDate": "2018-5-18"
}];

var json2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  json2.push({
    [json[i].sCategory]: json[i].val,
    "CreatedDate": json[i].CreatedDate
  });
}
//The line below is for demo only.
console.log(json2);
```